# Is it possible to hide bottom navigation bar permanently in Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen

I want to hide the bottom navigation bar permanently(until the app closes) in my activity.

I was able to hide it with this

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

But when I touches the screen it shows again.

I searched alot and find this piece of code which works only for Android 4.4+.

```
View decor_View = getWindow().getDecorView();

int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

decor_View.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);
```

After the hours of research, I think we cannot hide it permanently in Jelly Bean or lower version directly. But there should be some trick or hack to disable the navigation bar showing again on touching the screen. Or atleast hiding  the buttons on the navigation bar.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Not without a rooted device.

Comment: @JonasCz what about using some listeners to listen the touch event on the screen and hiding it again ? I am new to androit. I don't whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Maybe - I don't think so though. But you could try :-)